# Are English diphthongs nasalized before nasals?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, diphthongs

I learned that vowels are often nasalized before nasals ([Nasalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasalization)). It means that the velum is lowered when the vowel is produced in the mouth and most of the air comes out through nose. For example, the [a] in the word "man" is nasalized because it comes before the nasal [n]. We mark nasalization by a tilde over the nasalized vowel.

"Man" = [mãn]

I didn't find any information about diphthongs nasalization and I wonder if they are nasalized before nasals.

For example, the diphthong [aɪ] comes before a nasal in the word "mine". Is it nasalized? If it is, how should I represent it?

**[mãɪ̃n]** or **[maɪ̃n]**?

Which vowel between the two vowels of a diphthong is nasalized? And where should the tilde go?

There are some disagreements in the comments. I believe most people here confused my question with "spelling", which is not my concern. This is IPA transcription, not spelling. French has nasalized vowels in "spelling" so that's completely different.

Comment: Have you found any cases in English of nasal vowels that have a phonemic difference from oral vowels?

Comment: @livresque I don't think so. If I understand it correctly, nasalization is phonetic and not phonemic. In English, oral and nasalized vowels behave the same. (Are you hinting something about the brackets? I don't understand the difference between // and [] yet. They give me a very hard time but I have changed the brackets to [])

Comment: The *n* is different between *man* and *mankind* but I'm not sure the *a* is. If oral and nasalised vowels behave the same, why would there be a different symbol in IPA for English? (I've never seen tildes in IPA, but that may simply laziness or difficulty in adding them.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach My apologies. I meant "**phonemically**, they behave the same" although I am not completely sure.

Comment: Broad transcription (phonemic) with slashes //  vs. narrow (phonetic) with brackets [].  Don't let that bother you here. I just don't know any nasal vowels in English; it's always the nasal consonants that influence, so I'm confused.  Agree with @AndrewLeach (they're the same) and that's why there's no different symbol.

Comment: Please note that you asked this question on another stack:  https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37204/is-a-diphthong-nasalized-before-a-nasal

Comment: It's already been answered on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37204/is-a-diphthong-nasalized-before-a-nasal)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul There’s an answer There, but it hasn’t been answered, so to speak.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: The OP has accepted *that* answer though.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul They probably felt they ought to, given their respondent’s rep. But the fact that felt they had to ask here shows it hasn’t been. How do you mark (the very real, uncontroversial and well-established) nasalisation here?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: To be honest, I've never transcribed a nasalised diphthong. I don't know how.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul But that's what the OP asked, so QED that other answer doesn't answer the question! ;-)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul The answer to that question on Linguistics SE does not at all answer my question. I accepted it because; first, I got a couple of close votes and disagreements, read the comments you will see. Second, the answerer gave me an answer instead of closing my question like others right away, so I had to accept it. See here, I got one downvote and 2 close even here. I haven't got the answer I am looking for. And the only answer here: I don't understand how it addresses my question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for your support! Yes, the answer on Linguistics SE does not answer my question as I explained in the above comment.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. :( Wish you could write an answer

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes I saved them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the question as to how to represent nasalized diphthongs in IPA, Portuguese offers the answer. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_vowel) says:

> Portuguese also allows nasal diphthongs that contrast with their oral counterparts, like the pair mau /ˈmaw/ "bad" and mão /ˈmɐ̃w̃/ "hand".

So in Portuguese, you put the nasalization diacritic on both elements of the diphthong.

In comments,  Araucaria pointed out that a tilde over both elements of the diphthong: [a͠ɪ], would be better notation for a nasalized [aɪ] in IPA. However, this doesn't seem to be the standard ... possibly because of typogrphical considerations when IPA for Portuguese was first introduced, although it's not hard to do using Unicode today. And if you want an extremely narrow transcription, you might want to let your choice of symbols depend on how far into the diphthong the nasalization starts.

Comment: Thanks Peter Shor for your answer!

Comment: As for the question of whether English nasalizes diphthongs, I think so. That is, I think I can feel a slight nasalization when I compare my pronunciations of *faint* and *fate*, *timed* and *tide*, *don't* and *dote*, etc.

Comment: [This article](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/all#California-Vowel-Shift-English-%C3%A6-%C9%AA) has a short note: "æ ɪ → e i / _ŋ; some speakers (esp. in southern regions) may also have pin-pen and “a single phoneme in contrast to the *nasal diphthong* **[ãɪ̃]** of the U.S. Northeast” (though the article doesn’t specify what this is; maybe it’s just plain ã)" /// They've also transcribed it with a tilde over both vowels.

Comment: Portuguese even has nasal triphthongs and more, great example from [this blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/07/portuguese.html) "The word têm has the superficially improbable pronunciation ˈtɐ̃ĩ̯ɐ̃ĩ̯."   Sorry if this is off-topic here, but it supports your answer of the nasal tilde for each IPA vowel.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: Since many southern speakers use [a] for the phoneme /aɪ/, I think that it most likely is indeed plain [ã].